# Repeatedly re-writing JSON and getting undefined due to re-write

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am currently generating some data in Python and saving the corresponding data to a JSON file. This data grows quite quickly although it is not large to the point where it will be an issue, it is also re-generated fairly fast. I am then reading this data into Javascript at a very fast rate. The issue I am having is most of the time when I am requesting the JSON data the file is returning undefined in the python size due to the fact that I re-write the JSON file each time which causes the data to be undefined. The solution I am looking for would lead to the file being undefined for far less time, I could potentially switch to other methods for transferring data between Python and Javascript if any spring to mind.

Comment: Please share code.  This question is not actionable or answerable right now because it doesn't show us what you are trying to do, just posing the question "how do I do X?"

Comment: You could alternate between 2 files.